# When using LINQ, what is the difference between && and multiple where clauses?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am new to LINQ and discovered yesterday that you can have multiple where clauses such as:

```
var items = from object in objectList
where object.value1 < 100  
where object.value2 > 10  
select object;
```

Or you can write:

```
var items = from object in objectList
where object.value1 < 100  
   && object.value2 > 10  
select object;
```

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first one will be translated into:

```
objectList.Where(o => o.value1 < 100).Where(o=> o.value2 > 10)
```

while the second one will be translated in:

```
objectList.Where(o => o.value1 < 100 && o.value2 > 10)
```

So, in the first one, you will have a first filtered sequence that is filtered again (first sequence contains all the objects with value < 100, the second one containing all the objects with value > 10 from the first sequence), in while the second one you will do the same comparisons in the same labda expression. This is valid fro Linq to objects, for other providers it depends how the expression is translated.

Comment: Actually that's quite inaccurate. If you inspect `Linq`'s sources you will see that `Where` has a method which translates `.Where(x).Where(y)` into `.Where(x && y)`. [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f7e72dc9c9621f30)

Comment: Good point, I'm unable to say if I checked this back in 2009 or if it was true all along.

Answer (score 18):

***The marked answer gets it a little bit inaccurate.***

As @Philippe said, the first one will be translated into:

```
objectList.Where(o => o.value1 < 100).Where(o=> o.value2 > 10)
```

while the second one will be translated in:

```
objectList.Where(o => o.value1 < 100 && o.value2 > 10)
```

***But*** `Linq` has a little optimization for chained `Where` calls.

If you inspect `Linq's` source code you will see the following:

```
class WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource> : Iterator<TSource>
{
    public override IEnumerable<TSource> Where(Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, 
            CombinePredicates(this.predicate, predicate));
    }
}
```

What `CombinePredicates` does is is combining the two predicates with `&&` between them:

```
static Func<TSource, bool> CombinePredicates<TSource>(Func<TSource, bool> predicate1,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate2)
{
    return x => predicate1(x) && predicate2(x);
}
```

So `objectList.Where(X).Where(Y)` is equivalent to `objectList.Where(X && Y)` except for the creation time of the query (Which is extremely short anyway) and the invocation of two predicates.

Bottom line is that ***it does not*** filter or iterate the collection two times - but one composite time.

Answer (score 6):

The first one translates to:

```
objectList.Where(o => o.value1 < 100)
          .Where(o => o.value2 > 10);
```

while the latter gets you:

```
objectList.Where(o => o.value1 < 100 && o.value2 > 10);
```

It's functionally the same, and while the second one would spare a method call, the difference in performance is negligible. Use what's more readable for you.

That is, if you're using LINQ to Objects. If you're using a provider, it depends on how it's implemented (if the predicate is not factored in the resulting query, the result can be sub-optimal).

Comment: I actually typed it directly. You're right, the identity selector does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

I've just profile it.
No difference in SQL code

Comment: Assuming the OP was talking about LINQ to SQL. =)

Answer (score 1):

At the most basic level, you get two Where operations instead of one. Using Reflector is the best way to examine what comes out the other end of a query expression.

Whether they get optimised down to the same thing depends on the actual LINQ provider - it needs to take the entire tree and convert it to another syntax. For LINQ To Objects, it doesn't.

[C# in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988363) is good to give you an understanding of this topic.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for an answer: with && you can't guarantee that both expressions with be evaluated (if the first condition is false then the second might not be evaluated).  With the two where clauses then you can.  No idea whether it's true but it sounds good to me!

Comment: I don't think that's true. If it's Linq to Objects, the first Where-call will return an enumeration only containing the items where condition 1 is true. So condition 2 will only be called for these items.

Comment: Right, but isn't the opposite true? Let's say you use a simple '&', then both will be evaluated in the second case. Anyway, better avoid using side effects in these :)

Answer (score 0):

All other things being equal, I would choose the `condition1 && condition2` version, for the sake of code readability.