# complex linq-to-sql join with 4 tables: how many where clauses should there be?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm writing a linq-to-sql query that joins 4 tables. I have something like this:

```
var MyQuery = from a in MyDC.Table1
              from b in MyDC.Table2
              from c in MyDC.Table3
              from d in MyDC.Table4
              where .....
```

My question is about the `where` clause(s). I could write the where clause in one like this:

```
   where a.PropX == b.PropY && b.PropX == c.PropZ && ....
```

or multiple clauses like this:

```
   where a.PropX == b.PropY
   where b.PropX == c.PropZ
   ...
```

Is there going to be any difference in choosing one option or the other?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673184/whats-the-difference-between-multiple-where-clauses-and-operator-in-linq-to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer neither of the above; instead I would follow the SQL syntax, which doesn't hide the intent of the query as so:

```
var query  from a in MyDC.Table1 
           join b in MyDC.Table2 on a.Property1 equals b.Property2
           join c in MyDC.Table3 on b.Property1 equals c.Property5
           join d in MyDC.Table4 on c.Property2 equals d.Property1
select ...
```

Comment: +1: Why bother with complicated where clauses when the syntax is built in?

Answer (score 1):

You should not do it this way. Your code will produce a Cartesian join (multiplication) of all data sources and then filter it according to your criteria. Instead you should use simple joins as Icarus suggests.

(I understand where your confusion comes from: in some SQL dialects you can write join conditions either in `WHERE` or in `JOIN`. But that' not the case with LINQ.)